# How to Fill Up Input boxes from data base based on 1st Entry.?

Tags: php, javascript

First I'm New to PHP and JavaScript.

I have more then one input boxes for date Entering in PHP.
what I would like to do is if user Enter date in first input box based on this entered date, Rest of the input boxes should fill up automatically from SQL tables (which has date by week) when leave from 1st input box(OnChange).

I don't have any idea about it how can i do that.
Any helps will be appreciate..
Thank you

i have this code for the input boxes

```
echo '<div class = "start_date" >'; //Start_Date class start
echo '<strong><label for="start_date">Start Date</label></strong>';
echo '<br/><br/>'; 
for($k=1;$k<=$textboxindex;$k++)
    {
    echo "<input type=\"text\" class='textboxsize' id= \"inputField$k\" name=\"start_date[]\" value=\"$start_date\" tabindex='$k'/>";
    echo "<br/>";
    }

echo '</div>'; //Start_date Class End
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use javascript to run an ajax call to pre-populate the other select boxes.

```
$('.date1').change(function() {
 //prepopulate other select boxes

$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/date2.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.date2').html(data);

  }
});
});
```

Comment: I am new on It. Can you explain in detail plz

Comment: Do you have more samples of your code. Why must the data come from sql? The data is just dates? What other types of input boxes follow, what data do they contain?

Comment: The date1 change gets triggered when the contents of the input has changed, this then will trigger an ajax call - with has a url to the backend of your site - possibly with the value of the date just entered. ajax/date2.html?date=newdate

Comment: You can get newdate -- by var newdate = $(this).val()

Comment: i have calander popup in the date input box by clicking on it.

Comment: but what i want to have if the 1st input box date is "monday" like "2012-11-05" then next input box will be "2012-11-12" aftert next will be next monday.

Comment: Are you using a javascript calendar from jquery ui? - There could be a function that allows you to get the next day - without having to call any sql/backend pages.

Comment: no i'm not using it. But how can I use it for next input box pop up.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.date1').change(function() {
 //prepopulate other select boxes

    var newDate = $(this).val();

    var date = new Date(newDate);//if its not already a timestamp
    var theday = date.getDate();
    var themonth = date.getMonth()+1;
    var theyear = date.getFullYear();

    var nextDay = new Date(theyear+'-'+themonth+'-'+theday+1);//if its not already a timestamp

$('.date2').val(nextDay);

});
```

Comment: I need to call in input box .?

Comment: @Rob Please don't post twice while replying to a single post..You can always append a second code to the existing reply, in case there are more than one..